# How to check if a jQuery Cycle slideshow is terminated with this log " [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1 "

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I've to check if a jQuery Cycle slideshow is terminated.
I need to check this becouse I have multiple slideshow,
I run it in sequence, but, when the log " [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1 " appears,
becouse the slideshow has only one page, it blocks all the Cycle options 'after' and 'before'
and so it do not works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's causing you problems, you might need to elaborate on the exact issue that's happening. You could just check to see if any slides exist before initializing cycle, like so:

```
if ($('#slideshow').children().length > 1) {
    $('#slideshow').cycle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fix within Cycle but an easier approach would be not to attach Cycle functionality to "slideshows" with less than two items.

Edit: Exactly what @Christian Varga sussests.